# Is this stateful web service/wcf service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, stateful

Service layer has a login method which accepts username and password and returns a unique session id (a guid) if the account is valid.

On subsequent request the same session id will be passed instead of passing username and password, so is this stateful or stateless, because I don't need any state information except the authentication of each request

Answer (score 1):

The client connects, exchanges data, stores it somewhere, and disconnects. Upon subsequent connections the SAME DATA must be passed back to the server. This is not stateful.

In a stateful connection, you would connect, authenticate, and then simply use the service. The server would "remember" you without having to constantly be reminded of your session ID. This is definitely stateless.

Comment: on the server side , the session id will be stored so that on subsequent requests it can be verified

Comment: Yes but it's stored on disk, not in memory. Furthermore the client needs to constantly remind the server, "hey it's me again". That's not stateful.

Comment: State can be faked using storage (e.g. cookies). The setup itself, however is inherently stateless.

Comment: Actually wcf sessions hosted in asp.net will be stored by default inProc which is in memory.

Comment: @LDAdams: ok, well that was my bad. OK so it's a faster storage, but it still needs to be reminded who the client is.

Comment: so what will be a better approach...passing username password with each service call or passing session id

Comment: @taher: session id, definitely.

Comment: @chris...i am confused between LDAAdams and yours answer

Answer (score 1):

I would say it could be considered stateful. The server is storing information regarding your session including client activity (timeout, etc).  I could also see the argument especially in the Java world where stateless and stateful Beans are much more well defined.